# Logged in session timeout notification with Resource Owner Password with IdentityServer4 and Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, identityserver4

I am using Resource Owner Password with IdentityServer4 and Xamarin Android.

Is it possible to get notification when logged in user's session time out. So login form can be prompted to user again.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean when the IdentityServer session cookie expires or when the access token expires?

Comment: I am not aware of IdentiyServer session cookie, what is IdentityServer session cookie for? Does only access token control the session timeout?

Comment: The session cookie is what tells IdentityServer that you’ve already authenticated when you hit the authorize endpoint, effectively skipping the login page. The access token has a different purpose of being used to delegate authorization to a client application. Why do you need to have the notification built into IdentityServer? You could achieve the same functionality by having the Xamarin app take note of the expiry time in the access token itself.

Comment: Thanks Thanks  @Randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the resource owner password grant type there's not really the concept of a "session" as there is with authorize endpoint flows (which involve an authentication cookie and browser redirects). The lifetime of the access token is the thing you need to be aware of and you can renew it at any time and also inspect it for its expiry time.

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks